# Linux Kernel page compression & modify writeback mechanism

Tags: kernel, compression

I'm trying to compress the page that will be wrriten-back to backing store. (swap)
I'm using LZO compression library in kernel .

when I print compressed length of page, it looks like working properly.
that means there's no problems in compression.

but, write-back mechanism drives me crazy.
it is using bio structure for block device I/O. before write pages back, put the page(compressed) in

```
bio->bi_io_vec[0].bv_page = comp_page;
bio->bi_io_vec[0].bv_len = comp_len;
....
bio->bi_size = comp_len;
bio->sector = map_swap_page(origin_page, &bio->bi_bdev);
```

and then i've got following message... (OOPS)

any idea for compression swapping...?
I wanna develop it by myself not using zswap or zram...

Comment: sorry your left a lot for imagination, please provide either full source code, or the specific OOPS (which i think is still not enough, as solving one OOPS will still leads to other OOPS if any parts of the complex operation is not right). alternatively, looking at mm/zswap.c as a model to learn insight helps too.

Comment: thank you. I forgot what I should uploaded. I'll do details in next time when I get a curious thing or questions to u guys. thanks again.

Comment: i think this approach of compressing to physical swap space is going to suffer a lot in terms of performance:  why save space on the disk?   (trading off for spending time in compressing/decompressing).   Another approach is zram:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram   take a look, it is now available...and make a lot more sense.